# how can I select only specific .nc files from long list to work with cdo?

Tags: bash, filenames, cdo-climate

How can I merge only specific .nc files to work with `cdo`?
from a long list of files that look like this:

var_1-2.nc

var_3-4.nc

var_5-6.nc

.

.

var_99-100.nc

I would like to to a cdo mergetime only to the last e.g 10 files
Anyone could help me with the syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for this issue is:

```
cdo mergetime $(ls | tail -n 10) outfile.nc
```

Comment: Yes, but one always has to be sure that the files are listed in the order you expect. For this kind of thing I would always suggest trying out the "ls | tail -n 10" command on its own first to be sure that you are merging what you intended. :-)

Answer (score 1):

CDO can accept wild cards. Based on what you have said the following should work:

```
cdo mergetime var_99*.nc out.nc
```

Comment: sometimes wildcards can be tricky... in fact this command would miss var90-91, var91-92 etc, but if instead you tried var_9* you would pick up var9-10 by mistake...  I would suggest using ? instead of * to make it more robust

Comment: Correct. Smart thing is to pad the 9 with a 0 in the first place. ;)

Comment: Indeed! seq -w would do wonders here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rob's answer, it is perhaps more robust to do

```
cdo mergetime var_9?-*.nc out.nc
```

The `?` can only be replaced by a single character so this would pick up all the 90s files but ignore var9-10.nc

Of course if you wanted only the last 7 files then this wouldn't work and your `tail` solution is better.

As Rob mentions in his comments, in general it is a good idea to pad file name indices with zeros when generating them, so that a list command like `ls` will give them in correct numerical order - you can do this with `seq -w i1 i2` for example.